# Regarding Push Notification In Worklight?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

1. Push Notification had been executed and worked perfectly in my
   application. (I made use of worklight push notification module [IBM
   LINK](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/PushNotificationsHybridProject.zip))
2. There was a scenario which i experienced during the
   notification received in the application android device.
3. The push notification is received perfectly in all the situtaion except when i am in the Login Screen(When i am in the login screen of the application the push notification is not received in my application).

Question :

1. Why push notification is not received in the application ?
2. What is the client side (Device side) architecture/execution flow  , by which i can
   understand when is the PushNotification Receiver (Broad Cast
   Receiver) in device is ready to receive the notification and when it
   can't receive notifications ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

You've implemented event source-based pus notifications. In this type of push notifications you must first login in order to receive notification. This is why while you're at the login screen, you will not receive the notification.

If you are using either Worklight 6.2 or MobileFirst Platform 6.3, you can use tag or broadcast-based notifications which do not require a login.

You can read more about these at the IBM MobileFirst Platform developer center.

Here is a rundown of possible scenarios:

1. Application is closed - notification arrives to device - by opening the application / tapping the notification in the notification bar, you will get a login screen. After you login you will actually see the payload (in the way you choose to, that's purely applicative). You will not see the actual payload, because you don't want user B for example to see the payload of user A.
2. Application is opened - you are logged in, but the app is in the background - notification arrives to the device - by tapping the notification or bringing the application to the foreground, because you are already logged in, you'll see the payload
3. Application is opened - you are NOT logged in - notification arrives to the device - you will not be able to see the payload, because you are not logged in.
4. Application is opened - you are logged in, and the app is in the foreground - notification arrives to the device - you will immediately see the payload (per your applicative code)

Comment: Let me clearly say the scenario i have logged in and again while app is running in background i can get notification but once i open the app again it moves to the login screen and at that time i cant receive the notification but after that i close the app without logining in again the notification which i was not able to receive when i was in login screen has arrived at this point. Thats y i am confussed whats happening in my device side ?

Comment: Ya i got the things and the above scenarios i tested and got what u said but still i can't get why my application cant receive notification's when in login screen.

Comment: Event source notifications are sent per user. If two users use the same applications, you don't want user B to get data belonging to user A. This is how the feature is implemented. When the app is opened, the app it self handles the notification and not the OS, so you will not see the notification in the notification bar, as if already arrived to the app.